# ¿Como capturar teclado o combinacion de teclas en python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola quisiera saber como puedo capturar combinaciones de teclas en [python3](/questions/tagged/python3), por ejemplo al presionar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ejecute un método en una clase. Es para un programa en consola y esto es lo que he encontrado hasta ahora de información.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import rlcompleter
import readline

readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
grupo_a = set([1, 2, 3])

cmd = None

while cmd not in ['quit', 'exit']:
    cmd = input('>> ')
    exec(cmd)
```

Comment: ¿Estamos hablando de aplicaciones en consola no de Interfaces gráficas verdad (TKinter, PyQt, Kivy, etc)? Por otro lado, ¿para que sistema operativo?, porque las opciones varian dependiendo de ello. Saludos.

Comment: Hola es para un sistema linux,  es para una plicacion de consola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de abordar esto y depende de lo que quieras hacer al final. Agregando otras posibilidades a lo ya expuesto por Patricio en su respuesta:

En Linux puedes usar [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) de la biblioteca estándar para crear aplicaciones en terminal mejoradas usando `ncurses`. Facilita la presentación de las salidas/entradas (mediante tabulacion), colores, bordes de ventana, permite responder a eventos de teclado (como combinaciones de teclas), etc. Un ejemplo algo simple usando combinaciones de teclas (Alt+P, Alt+A, Alt+E) para llamar a funciones (nada optimizado):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import curses

def get_param(screen, prompt_string):
     curses.echo()
     screen.clear()
     screen.addstr(2, 2, prompt_string)
     screen.refresh()
     input = screen.getstr(2, len(prompt_string)+2, 60)
     return input

def sumar(screen):
    curses.noecho()
    n = int(get_param(screen, 'Ingrese un número: '))
    m = int(get_param(screen, 'Ingrese otro número: '))
    screen.addstr(2, 2, 'La suma de {} y {} es {}.'.format(n, m, n + m))
    screen.addstr(4, 2, 'Pulse Enter para volver al menú')
    while True:
        ch = screen.getch()
        if ch == 10: #Enter
            main(screen)
            break

def restar(screen):
    curses.echo()
    n = int(get_param(screen, 'Ingrese un número: '))
    m = int(get_param(screen, 'Ingrese otro número: '))
    screen.addstr(2, 2, 'La resta de {} y {} es {}.'.format(n, m, n - m))
    screen.addstr(4, 2, 'Pulse Enter para volver al menú')
    while True:
        ch = screen.getch()
        if ch == 10: #Enter
            main(screen)
            break


def main(screen):
    curses.echo()
    while True:
        screen.clear()
        screen.border(0)
        screen.addstr(2, 2, "Alt+A para sumar dos numeros")
        screen.addstr(3, 2, "Alt+P para restar dos numeros")
        screen.addstr(4, 2, "Alt+E para salir de la app")
        ch = screen.getch(5, 2)

        if ch == 27: #Tecla Alt
            screen.nodelay(True)
            ch2 = screen.getch() # obtener tecla pulsada despues de Alt
            if ch2 == -1 or ch2 == ord('e') or ch2 == ord('E'):
                break
            elif ch2 == ord('a') or ch2 == ord('A'):
                screen.nodelay(False)
                sumar(screen)
                break
            elif ch2 == ord('p') or ch2 == ord('P'):
                screen.nodelay(False)
                restar(screen)
                break
            else:
                screen.refresh()
            screen.nodelay(False)


curses.wrapper(main)
```

Otra opción puede ser usar una de las tantas librerías que hay para capturar/controlar acciones de teclado/ratón. Son tipicamente usadas para implementar keyloggers pero pueden tener fines más 'correctos'. Entre ellos tenemos **pyxhook** o **Pynput**.

Answer (score 0):

En la terminal lo que he visto que se hace es usar `sys.stdin.read(1)`, el tema es que en el caso de una combinación de teclas, o la teclas de función, o los PgUp/Dwn, las flechas y etcetera, hay que leer más de una vez, por ejemplo para un <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> habría que leer el <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, detectar que se trata de una tecla "especial" y luego leer nuevamente <kbd>A</kbd>, además me imagino que esto puede llegar a variar mucho de terminal a termina. Hay muchas "recetas" en la red para manejar esto, la que me gusto más por que resulta bastante explicativa es la que encontré [aquí](https://github.com/willkelleher/rokudo/blob/master/rokudo.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class _Getch:
    """
        Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the
        screen. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
        try:
            self.impl = _GetchWindows()
        except ImportError:
            self.impl = _GetchUnix()

    def __call__(self): return self.impl()


class _GetchUnix:
    def __init__(self):
        import tty, sys

    def __call__(self):
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        a=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            a[0]=ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
            if a[0]==27:
                a[1]=ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
            if a[1]==91:
                a[2]=ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
            if (a[2]>=49 and a[2]<=54) or a[2]==91:
                a[3]=ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
            if a[3]>=48 and a[3]<=57:
                a[4]=ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
            print(a)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)

        # Decode keypress
        # https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-June/367344.html
        if   a==[ 10,  0,  0,   0,   0, 0]: k=  13   # Enter
        elif a==[ 27, 27,  0,   0,   0, 0]: k=  27   # Esc (double press)
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 91,  65,   0, 0]: k=1059   # F1
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 91,  66,   0, 0]: k=1060   # F2
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 91,  67,   0, 0]: k=1061   # F3
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 91,  68,   0, 0]: k=1062   # F4
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 91,  69,   0, 0]: k=1063   # F5
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 49,  55, 126, 0]: k=1064   # F6
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 49,  56, 126, 0]: k=1065   # F7
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 49,  57, 126, 0]: k=1066   # F8
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 50,  48, 126, 0]: k=1067   # F9
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 50,  49, 126, 0]: k=1068   # F10
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 50,  51, 126, 0]: k=1133   # F11
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 50,  52, 126, 0]: k=1134   # F12
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 50, 126,   0, 0]: k=1082   # Ins
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 51, 126,   0, 0]: k=1083   # Del
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 49, 126,   0, 0]: k=1071   # Home
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 52, 126,   0, 0]: k=1079   # End
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 53, 126,   0, 0]: k=1073   # Pg Up
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 54, 126,   0, 0]: k=1081   # Pg Dn
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 65,   0,   0, 0]: k=1072   # Up
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 66,   0,   0, 0]: k=1080   # Down
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 68,   0,   0, 0]: k=1075   # Left
        elif a==[ 27, 91, 67,   0,   0, 0]: k=1077   # Right
        elif a==[127,  0,  0,   0,   0, 0]: k=   8   # Backspace
        else:                               k=a[0]   # Ascii code

        return k


class _GetchWindows:
    def __init__(self):
        import msvcrt

    def __call__(self):
        import msvcrt
        k=ord(msvcrt.getch())
        if k == 0 or k == 224:                    #Special keys
            return 1000+ord(msvcrt.getch())   #return 1000+ 2nd code
        else:
            return k


getkey = _Getch()

c = ""
#Salir con Ctrl-c
while c != 3:
    c = getkey()
    print(c)
```

Esto lo he probado en un Linux Mint 17, corre bien, pero algunas de las combinaciones ya definidas en el script no son exactamente iguales. Hay también una librería que parte del mismo concepto de trabajo que también puede responder a tu pregunta: [readchar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/readchar)

Answer (score 0):

Para leer el teclado podés usar ***Pynput***, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener # Importamos Pynput
```

def teclaPulsada(key): # Función para imprimir la tecla pulsada, puede ser reemplazada por un logger.

```
print("Pulsada: ", key) # Imprimimos tecla pulsada
```

with Listener(on_press=teclaPulsada) as listener: # Decimos Pynput que la función teclaPulsada debe ser llamada cuando se presione una tecla

`listener.join() # Iniciamos el listener`