# Estancado en problema con entrada de datos " " - Python

Tags: string, float

tengo una duda. He cogido "prestado" parte del código que se ha publicado en un mensaje de esta web, en concreto esto:

```
def get_param(screen, prompt_string):
    curses.echo()
    screen.clear()
    screen.addstr(2, 2, prompt_string)
    screen.refresh()
    entrada = screen.getstr(2, len(prompt_string)+2, 60)
    return input
```

La duda que tengo es en la línea:

```
    entrada = screen.getstr(2, len(prompt_string)+2, 60)
```

A esta línea le he añadido float delante de screen para poder introducir números en coma flotante. Quedando así la línea.

```
    entrada = float(screen.getstr(2, len(prompt_string)+2, 60))
```

El problema me surge en la introducción del dato que se introduce en ese input. Si pulso enter sin ningún dato, me sale error, este error:

File "/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX.py", line 9, in get_param entrada = float(screen.getstr(3, len(prompt_string) + 2, 9))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema?

Comment: La función float no establece el tipo de datos que soporta la entrada, lo único que hace es convertir un string a float. El error que te da es porque es incapaz de convertir un string vacío como un tipo de dato float.

Comment: La pregunta de referencia es esta: [Capturar teclado o combinacion de teclas Python 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71086/como-capturar-teclado-o-combinacion-de-teclas-en-python3). Desconozco el módulo [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html), pero a simple vista se ve en ese `input` no va `float`, ni `int`, ni nada de eso. Adicional recomendaría renombrar la variable `input`, ya que se está sobre-escribiendo una [función nativa](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) de Python.

Comment: Sí, la variable input la sustituí por entrada. No me parecía ideal tener input como variable. Efectivamente, el problema es que no se puede covertir " " en float, de la nada no se puede convertir algo. Si no le pongo float, cuando introduzco un dato con decimal, me sale error.

Comment: Vale, float lo he quitado y sí funciona get_param. Pero sigue dándome error al pulsar enter sin ningún dato.